# apache subdomain setup

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

Is it possible to setup a subdomain to point to a specific directory in `apache2`?
I would like `www.raspbianserver.com` to point to `/var/www/htdocs/index.html` and
`backend.raspbianserver.com` to point to `/var/www/backend/backend.php`

My current config file is

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@anatak.com
    ServerName www.raspbianserver.com
    ServerAlias raspbianserver.com
    Redirect / https://raspbianserver.com

    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.raspbianserver.com/htdocs/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/www.raspbianserver.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/www.raspbianserver.com/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/var/www/www.raspbianserver.com/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/www.raspbianserver.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www.raspbianserver.com/logs/access.log combined

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
```

Comment: This is not the full config file, and it is not all the config files. There are numerous peculiarities in it. What did you try so far? What resources have you researched?

Answer (score 1):

This [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) has a really nice tutorial on setting up multiple virtual hosts.

Basically you need a `<VirtualHost *:80 >` entry for each domain. Changing the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` as required. Ideally, you'd keep these in separate files as it makes things nicer if you need to enhance one of them; for example if you wanted to proxy to an application server of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

As Raspbian (I assume you use that) is a Debian distribution you should copy `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.rasbianserver.com.conf` and change the contents of that file to suit your needs.

Things you would like to change are which IP-addresses/interfaces to use (Like `*:80` in `VirtualHost`),  domain-name of the server (like `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`) and where the files are stored (like `DocumentRoot`) the locations of the access and error logs (`CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` to `/var/log/www/www.raspbinaserver.com-access.log` and `-error.lot`) etc.  I usually put them under the directory `/srv/www` as the directory `/srv` is supposed to be server data files.  But anywhere you like will do, as long as you use a system. Dont forget to set up the file rights and user/group for wherever you choose.

The when you have it set up the way you like, you need to enable the server, and that is done with the command `a2esite`:

```
sudo a2ensite www.rasbianserver.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or what `a2ensite` tells you to do.  You could also open another terminal window on your machine and there write this command to see what you get when starting and accessing the server.

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/www.rasbianserver.com-{access,error}.log
```

If you add yourself to the group `adm` you can look into logs without the need of sudo to the `tail` command.
If you need to activate modules, you install the right package and then use `a2enmod` command.  For more information, see `man a2enmod`, `man a2ensite` and `man a2enconf`.  Also look in [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/) and [The Debian Administrator's Handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/).